# Origine de l'expression « pain amer »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

« Pain amer » seems to be a common enough expression that [movies](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_amer) and [books](https://www.amazon.ca/Pain-amer-J-Lengyel/dp/2207280357) are given this title, and it is the subject of this wordplay of Camus' in *La peste*:

> La souffrance des enfants était notre pain amer, mais sans ce pain, notre âme périrait de sa faim spirituelle.

Yet it seems not to be common enough to appear under a separate heading in dictionaries, even [Expressio](https://www.expressio.fr/).

In [a Google Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pain%20amer&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpain%20amer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpain%20amer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPain%20amer%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cpain%20amer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpain%20amer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPain%20amer%3B%2Cc0), the first batch of uses (1700-1777) seem to be literal (e.g. « le seigle fait du pain amer »), and the next batch (1778–1857) seem to treat it as an expression already (e.g. [« Manger un pain amer détrempé de ses larmes »](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FK1fAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA584&lpg=PA584&dq=Manger%20le%20pain%20de%20la%20chaumi%C3%A8re.-Manger%20un%20pain%20amer%20d%C3%A9tremp%C3%A9%20de%20ses%20larmes&source=bl&ots=hKGGykAs4F&sig=ACfU3U1JVg6HvfSyf2ACZTwd-y_lnY-eJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFh8mY1NLoAhUjTt8KHYzOASUQ6AEwAHoECAoQKQ#v=onepage&q=Manger%20le%20pain%20de%20la%20chaumi%C3%A8re.-Manger%20un%20pain%20amer%20d%C3%A9tremp%C3%A9%20de%20ses%20larmes&f=false)).

What is the origin? It feels vaguely biblical. But many biblical expressions have calques in English since both are calqued from the original Hebrew or Greek idiom (cf. *feet of clay* / *pieds d'argile*), whereas I can't think of a ready-made equivalent for « pain d'amer » in English.

Comment: "Bitter bread" is at least as much used - if not more - in English as it is in French, has been for long (cf Shakespeare's famous quote "the bitter bread of banishment" where it is already used with a figurative meaning). Run an [ngram](https://bit.ly/2X85Y7g) to get several examples. And it is used in lots of languages other than French and English so I do not think the question is specific to the French Language.

Comment: Bitter bread is a name given to brown bread, [brown bread having a bitter taste](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/32405/26082), and brown bread is considered as inferior and therefore poor people's bread.

Comment: You can't grammatically and semantically compare *pieds d'argile* where *argile* is a noun defining a material, with *pain amer* where *amer* is an adjective describing a characteristic. *Pain d'amer* as you write it would be an impossible construction, *amer* being used there as a noun, whereas *amer* is only used as an adjective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no explanation and origin of the phrase that is specific to French. The phrase is used in other languages (bitter bread, bitteres Brot, pane amaro etc.) with exactly the same literal and figurative meanings.

Comment: I personally never heard that expression...

Comment: @None Hmm, I didn't realize it was in Shakespeare! Nevertheless, it doesn't have the feel of an expression toute faite as it does in French — to me, anyway; maybe Laurent is right and there's nothing special about it. When you read the Camus sentence, do you find the metaphor novel or familiar? If novel, it's a literature question, but if familiar, I think it's a French (enough) question. And sure, there could be similar expressions in other languages, but one or the other has to be our door to the origin :) If it's used with a figurative meaning in general, I'd like to know where that began.

Comment: The reason for bringing up "pieds d'argile" is not to make a comparison with "pain amer", but to give an example of a biblical phrase that is easily identified because it has an exact calque in English ("feet of clay"), the reason being that both are calqued from the original language — whereas "bitter bread", to me, lacks the idiomatic feeling that "pain amer" has. It's a counterexample.

Comment: [It may be that this is just a lacuna in my mental database of English expressions...](https://www.filmlinc.org/nyff2019/films/bitter-bread/)

Answer (score 1):

L'expression « un pain  amer » connaît des fortunes diverses dans les langues européennes.  Elle est associée le plus souvent à la douleur de l'exil.  Elle appartient à un fonds commun de la culture européenne qui trouve sa source dans *La Divine Comédie* du Dante, plus précisément , dans le chant XVII du *Paradis* :

> Tu lascerai ogne cosa diletta
>
> più caramente; e questo è quello strale
>
> che l'arco de lo essilio pria saetta.
>
> Tu proverai sì come sa di sale
>
> lo pane altrui, e come è duro calle
>
> lo scendere e 'l salir per l'altrui scale.

Dans les traductions françaises, on retrouve souvent l'image du *pain amer* pour rendre les vers du Florentin :

> « Tu seras obligé d'abandonner ce qui te sera le plus cher : c'est la première flèche que lance l'arc de l'exil.  Tu apprendras combien le pain étranger est amer et combien il est dur de monter et descendre l'escalier d'autrui. »  (Traduction d'Artaud de Montor, début du 19e siècle.)
>
> « Tu éprouveras combien le pain de l'étranger recèle d'amertume, et quel dur chemin c'est de monter et de descendre l'escalier d'autrui. » (Traduction de Saint-Mauris, milieu du 19e siècle.)
>
> « Tu éprouveras combien d'autrui le pain est amer et quel dur chemin est le monter et le descendre par l'escalier d'autrui. » (Traduction de Lamennais, milieu du 19e siècle.)
>
> « Tu sentiras alors quel sel amer on goûte
>
> Au pain de l'étranger, et quelle dure route
>
> De descendre et monter par l'escalier d'autrui ! »
>
> (Traduction de Ratisbonne, milieu du 19e siècle.)